# Grammatical status of question tags

Tags: grammar

When a question tag is added to a simple sentence, what does the combined sentence become? (compound sentence/complex sentence)

Can it be classified as co-ordinate clause?

If question tag clause is classified as dependent clause, then obviously the sentence becomes a complex sentence. So, in that case, which category (Noun/Adjective/Adverb) of dependent clause will question tag fall in?

Comment: What gain might anyone have from this piece of terminology/classification **when learning English**? This looks like another valueless homework question, where none of the terms involved have a clear definition. If you're doing this to yourself, you have my permission to abandon it and do something worthwhile: read a book / watch a movie that interests you. If you're actually interested in English grammar, start reading books that deal with it; I recommend you begin with the textbook titled *A Student's Introduction to English Grammar* by Huddleston and Pullum.

Answer (score 0):

When you add a question tag, for example:

"What time is it?" /he asked/

It becomes a compound sentence, since it constrains two independent clauses. Both "What time is it?" And "He asked" can stand alone as their own sentences. So while we treat a dialogue tag as part of the same sentence, in the way we only separate them by a comma or the respective sign (interrogation or exclamation) it is in fact a sentence of it's own, with a subject and verb.

The easiest way to remember it is that a compound sentence is composed of two sentences acting together. If you separate them, they can still stand on their own.

On the other hand, a complex sentence informed by joining an independent clause (a full sentence) with a subordinate clause (something that has a subject AND a verb yet lacks context or meaning and therefore cannot be it's own sentence)

Examples of this.

> "You ate the last pizza slice!"

He exclaimed. This is a compound sentence. Both "you ate the last pizza slice" and "he exclaimed" have subject, verb and context.

"The football match was canceled, because it was raining" this is a complex sentence. "The football match was canceled" is an independent clause (it has a subject, verb and context) while "because it was raining" is a subordinate clause (it has subject and verb but lacks a clear meaning on its own, it needs to be paired to another sentence for it to make sense).

Comment: Tag questions are added as attachments to declarative sentences like "He is tall,  isn't he" and my question was what is the status of this tag question "isn't he" in the complete sentence. Thanks